# Selenium cant find the second element inside the same frame

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

While I can select the first element, I am having troubles selecting the second one which is inside the same frame than the first one.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')
main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)

#This works perfectly
driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")
dropdown_secciones = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select')

select_box_secciones = Select(dropdown_secciones)
secciones = []
for item  in select_box_secciones.options:
    secciones.append(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

#But this doesn´t work

dropdown_circuitos_capital = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select[2]')
select_box_circuitos_capital = Select(dropdown_circuitos_capital)
circuitos_capital = []

for item  in select_box_circuitos_capital.options:
    circuitos_capital.append(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

When select_box_circuitos_capital.options nothing appears. Any ideas why?

This is the html code:

```
<select class="Combo" id="cmbCircuitos" onchange="LlenarComboCargo(this,this.item(this.selectedIndex).value)" style=""><option value="0">
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. I suggest putting `print()` statements before the `for` loop and inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath can be incredibly unreliable, especially if you're selecting using an absolute path. It's worth either refining your Xpath to be relative to a nearby attribute or if possible just avoid using it altogether.

Presumably your issue is that locator that sets 'dropdown_circuitos_capital' does not find an element. If this is the case you will need to provide your html in order to see why that locator fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The weird thing is that actually it does find an element but without its options value. When print(select_box_circuitos_capital) the output is: selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x0000020C21D50788

Comment: This is the html code:
<select class="Combo" id="cmbCircuitos" onchange="LlenarComboCargo(this,this.item(this.selectedIndex).value)" style="">

Answer (score 1):

Because you have targeted wrong element.Try this.

```
dropdown_circuitos_capital = driver.find_element_by_id('cmbCircuitosTodos')
select_box_circuitos_capital = Select(dropdown_circuitos_capital)
circuitos_capital = []

for item  in select_box_circuitos_capital.options:
    circuitos_capital.append(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

print(circuitos_capital)
```

Output:

```
['Seleccionar', '1    |SECCIONAL PRIMERA', '2    |SECCIONAL SEGUNDA', '3    |SECCIONAL TERCERA', '4    |NUEVA CORDOBA', '4A   |PUEBLO LAS FLORES', '4B   |VILLA REVOL', '4C   |INAUDI', '4D   |VILLA EUCARISTICA', '4E   |NUESTRO HOGAR III', '4F   |CIUDAD OBISPO ANGELELLI', '5    |ALTAMIRA', '5A   |COLONIA LOLA', '5B   |DEAN FUNES', '5C   |EMPALME', '5D   |MALDONADO', '5E   |VILLA BUSTOS', '5F   |RENACIMIENTO', '5G   |SAN VICENTE', '5H   |VILLA BOEDO', '5I   |COLINAS DEL SUR', '6    |ALTO GRAL PAZ', '6A   |BAJADA DE PIEDRA', '6B   |CHACRA DE LA MERCED', '6C   |GRAL PAZ', '6D   |JUNIORS', '6E   |LA FLORESTA SUD', '6F   |YAPEYU', '7    |AEROPUERTO', '7A   |GUIÑAZU', '7B   |ALTA CORDOBA', '7C   |CNO. A PAJAS BLANCAS', '7D   |COFICO', '7E   |MARQUES DE SOBREMONTE', '7F   |JORGE NEWBERY', '7G   |PANAMERICANO', '8    |LA FLORESTA NORTE', '8A   |PALMAR', '8B   |PUEYRREDON', '8C   |VILLA LOS PINOS', '9    |ESCOBAR', '9A   |LA FRANCE', '9B   |LAS MARGARITAS', '9C   |LOS PARAISOS', '9D   |POETA LUGONES', '9E   |PROVIDENCIA', '9F   |SAN MARTIN', '9G   |VILLA CABRERA', '10   |BELLA VISTA', '10A  |CABILDO', '10B  |CIUDADELA', '10C  |COMERCIAL', '10D  |CONGRESO', '10E  |ESTACION FLORES', '10F  |MATIENZO', '10G  |OBSERVATORIO', '10H  |PARQUE CAPITAL', '10I  |PARQUE HORIZONTE', '10J  |SANTA ISABEL', '10K  |VICOR', '10L  |VILLA EL LIBERTADOR', '10M  |AMPLIACION CABILDO', '11   |AERONAUTICO', '11A  |ALTO ALBERDI', '11B  |DON BOSCO', '11C  |LAS PALMAS', '11D  |LOS NARANJOS', '11E  |LOS PLATANOS', '11F  |LOS ROBLES', '11G  |PARQUE REPUBLICA', '11H  |QUEBRADA LAS ROSAS', '11I  |RESIDENCIAL SAN ROQUE', '11J  |SANTA ANA', '11K  |VILLA GRAL URQUIZA', '11L  |COUNTRYS DEL OESTE', '11M  |VALLE ESCONDIDO', '12   |AVELLANEDA', '12A  |CARCANO', '12B  |COLON', '12C  |CORONEL OLMEDO', '12D  |JOSE IGNACIO DIAZ', '12E  |FERREYRA', '12F  |JOSE HERNANDEZ', '12G  |ITUZAINGO', '12H  |LOS CERVECEROS', '12I  |CIUDAD DE MIS SUEÑOS', '13   |LEANDRO N. ALEM', '13A  |AYACUCHO', '13B  |EL GATEADO', '13C  |GENERAL BUSTOS', '13D  |JARDIN ARENALES', '13E  |LA DOROTEA', '13F  |NUEVA ITALIA', '13G  |PARQUE LICEO', '13H  |PATRICIOS', '13I  |SAN JORGE', '13J  |VILLA AZALAIS', '13K  |VILLA ESQUIU', '13L  |VILLA GRAN PARQUE', '13M  |CAMINO A COLONIA TIROLESA', '13N  |YOFRE', '13O  |CHACHAPOYAS', '14   |ARGUELLO', '14A  |ARGUELLO NORTE', '14B  |ARGUELLO PRIMERO', '14C  |ARGUELLO SEGUNDO', '14D  |CERRO DE LAS ROSAS', '14E  |CERRO NORTE', '14F  |GRANJA DE FUNES', '14G  |LOS BOULEVARES', '14H  |MERCANTIL', '14I  |SANTA CECILIA', '14J  |URCA', '14K  |VILLA ALLENDE PARQUE', '14L  |VILLA BELGRANO', '14M  |VILLA CENTENARIO', '14N  |VILLA CORNU', '14O  |VILLA 9 DE JULIO', '14P  |VILLA RIVERA INDARTE', '14Q  |VILLA WARCALDE', '15   |AMBOY', '15A  |VILLA AMANCAY', '16   |ATHOS PAMPA', '16A  |VILLA LA MERCED', '16B  |CHAMPAQUI', '16C  |VILLA BERNA', '17   |EMBALSE', '18   |LA CRUZ', '18A  |LUTTI', '18B  |CALERAS DE CALAMUCHITA', '18C  |VILLA CAÑADA DEL SAUCE', '18D  |VILLA QUILLINZO', '19   |LOS CONDORES', '20   |LOS REARTES', '20A  |VILLA GENERAL BELGRANO', '20B  |VI.CIUD.PQUE.LOS REARTES', '21   |LAS BAJADAS', '22   |RIO DE LOS SAUCES', '23   |VILLA YACANTO', '24   |RUMIPAL', '24A  |VILLA DEL DIQUE', '25   |SAN AGUSTIN', '25A  |CALMAYO', '25B  |LOS MOLINOS', '26   |SANTA ROSA', '26A  |SEGUNDA USINA', '26B  |SAN IGNACIO', '27   |ASCOCHINGA', '28   |CALERA', '28A  |CALERA CENTRAL', '29   |COLONIA CAROYA', '29A  |TINOCO', '30   |COLONIA TIROLESA', '31   |EL MANZANO', '31A  |AGUA DE ORO', '31B  |VILLA CERRO AZUL', '32   |GENERAL PAZ', '33   |JESUS MARIA', '33A  |COLONIA VICENTE AGÜERO', '34   |JUAREZ CELMAN', '35   |MALVINAS ARGENTINAS', '35A  |MI GRANJA', '36   |LA PUERTA', '37   |RIO CEBALLOS', '38   |SALSIPUEDES', '39   |SANTA TERESA', '40   |UNQUILLO', '40A  |MENDIOLAZA', '41   |VILLA ALLENDE', '41A  |SALDAN', '42   |BAÑADO DE SOTO', '43   |CANDELARIA', '43A  |LAS CAÑADAS', '43B  |CRUZ DE CAÑA', '43C  |CIENAGA DE BRITOS', '44   |CRUZ DEL EJE', '44A  |LAS PLAYAS', '45   |EL BRETE', '46   |GUANACO MUERTO', '46B  |ALTO DE LOS QUEBRACHOS', '47   |IGLESIA VIEJA', '48   |LA HIGUERA', '49   |LOS SAUCES', '50   |MEDIA NARANJA', '50A  |LOS CHAÑARITOS', '51   |PASO VIEJO', '51A  |SANTA ANA', '52   |PICHANAS', '53   |SAN ANTONIO', '53A  |LOS LEONES', '53B  |EL ABRA', '54   |SAN MARCOS SIERRAS', '54A  |CANTERAS QUILPO', '55   |SERREZUELA', '55A  |LA BATEA', '56   |SOTO', '57   |TUCLAME', '58   |BRUZONE', '59   |BUCHARDO', '60   |DEL CAMPILLO', '61   |HUINCA RENANCO', '62   |ITALO', '63   |JOVITA', '65   |LECUEDER', '66   |MATTALDI', '67   |ONAGOITY', '68   |PINCEN', '69   |RANQUELES', '70   |VILLA HUIDOBRO', '71   |VILLA SARMIENTO', '72   |VILLA VALERIA', '73   |ARROYO ALGODON', '74   |ARROYO CABRAL', '75   |AUSONIA', '76   |CHAZON', '77   |ETRURIA', '78   |LA LAGUNA', '79   |LA PLAYOSA', '80   |LUCA', '81   |MOJARRAS', '82   |PALESTINA', '83   |PASCO', '84   |SANABRIA', '86   |SILVIO PELLICO', '87   |TICINO', '88   |TIO PUJIO', '88A  |SANTA RITA', '88B  |SAN ANTONIO DE YUCAT', '89   |VILLA MARIA', '90   |VILLA NUEVA', '91   |AVELLANEDA', '91A  |CANTERAS', '91B  |LOS POZOS', '91C  |VILLA GUTIERREZ', '92   |CAÑADA DE RIO PINTO', '93   |COPACABANA', '94   |CHUÑA', '95   |DEAN FUNES', '96A  |OLIVARES SAN NICOLAS', '97   |ISCHILIN', '98   |JAIME PETER', '99   |QUILINO ESTACION', '100  |QUILINO VILLA', '101  |TOYOS', '102  |ALEJANDRO', '103  |ASSUNTA', '105  |BENGOLEA', '106  |CABRERA', '107  |CARNERILLO', '108  |CHARRAS', '109  |DEHEZA', '110  |EL RASTREADOR', '110A |PACHECO DE MELO', '111  |HUANCHILLA', '112  |LA CARLOTA', '113  |LOS CISNES', '114  |OLAETA', '116  |REDUCCION', '116A |PASO DEL DURAZNO', '117  |SANTA EUFEMIA', '118  |UCACHA', '119  |ALEJO LEDESMA', '120  |ARIAS', '121  |BALDISSERA', '122  |BARGE', '123  |CAMILO ALDAO', '124  |CAVANAGH', '125  |CORRAL DE BUSTOS', '126  |CRUZ ALTA', '127  |GUATIMOZIN', '128  |INRIVILLE', '128A |SALADILLO', '129  |ISLA VERDE', '130  |LA ITALIANA', '131  |LEONES', '131A |VILLA ELISA', '132  |LOS SURGENTES', '133  |MARCOS JUAREZ', '134  |MONTE BUEY', '135  |CAP.B.O HIGGINS', '136  |ROCA', '137  |SAIRA', '138  |CIENAGA DEL CORO', '138A |RUMIACO', '138B |RUMIHUASI', '138C |ESTANCIA DE GUADALUPE', '138D |TOSNO', '139  |GUASAPAMPA', '139A |AGUA DE RAMON', '139B |LA PLAYA', '140  |LA ARGENTINA', '140A |OJO DE AGUA DE TOTOX', '141  |PIEDRITA BLANCA', '141A |EL CHACHO', '142  |SAN CARLOS', '142A |TALAINI', '144  |CHANCANI', '144A |LAS JARILLAS', '144B |EL MEDANITO', '145  |POCHO', '145A |LAS PALMAS', '146  |SALSACATE', '146A |TALA CAÑADA', '146B |SAN JERONIMO', '146C |LOS TALARES', '147  |BIALET MASSE', '147A |SAN ROQUE', '147B |VILLA PARQUE SIQUIMAN', '148  |CAPILLA DEL MONTE', '149  |CASA GRANDE', '150  |COSQUIN', '151  |CHARBONIER', '152  |HUERTA GRANDE', '152A |VILLA GIARDINO', '153  |LA CUMBRE', '154  |LA FALDA', '155  |SAN ESTEBAN', '155A |LOS COCOS', '156  |VILLA CARLOS PAZ', '156A |YCHO CRUZ', '156B |CUESTA BLANCA', '156C |MAYU SUMAJ', '156D |SAN ANTONIO DE ARREDONDO', '156E |TALA HUASI', '157  |SANTA MARIA', '158  |TANTI', '158A |CABALANGO', '158B |ESTANCIA VIEJA', '158C |VILLA SANTA CRUZ DEL LAGO', '159  |VALLE HERMOSO', '160  |ACHIRAS', '160A |LA CAROLINA', '161  |ADELIA MARIA', '162  |ALCIRA', '163  |ALPA CORRAL', '164  |BAIGORRIA', '165  |BANDA NORTE', '166  |BERROTARAN', '167  |BULNES', '168  |CHAJAN', '169  |CHUCUL', '170  |ELENA', '171  |ESPINILLO', '172  |HOLMBERG', '173  |LA ARGENTINA', '174  |LA CAUTIVA', '175  |LA GILDA', '176  |LA INVERNADA', '177  |LAS ACEQUIAS', '178  |LAS CAÑITAS', '178A |LAS ALBAHACAS', '178B |VILLA EL CHACAY', '179  |LAS HIGUERAS', '180  |LAS PEÑAS', '181  |LOS CUATRO VIENTOS', '182  |LAS VERTIENTES', '183  |VICUÑA MACKENNA', '184  |MOLDES', '184A |MONTE DE LOS GAUCHOS', '185  |PAUNERO', '186  |PUEBLO ALBERDI', '187  |PUEYRREDON', '188  |RIO CUARTO', '189  |SAMPACHO', '190  |SAN AMBROSIO', '191  |SAN BASILIO', '191A |MALENA', '192  |SUCO', '193  |TOSQUITA', '194  |WASHINGTON', '195  |ATAHONA', '196  |CAÑADA DE MACHADO', '197  |LA POSTA', '198  |CAPILLA DE REMEDIOS', '199  |CHALACEA', '200  |DIEGO DE ROJAS', '201  |COLONIA LAS CUATRO ESQUINAS', '201A |LAS GRAMILLAS', '202  |ESQUINA', '203  |PEDRO E.VIVAS', '204  |LA PARA', '205  |LA PUERTA', '206  |LAS HERAS', '207  |LAS SALADAS', '208  |COMECHINGONES', '209  |MAQUINISTA GALLINI', '210  |BLAS DE ROSALES', '211  |MONTE CRISTO', '212  |MONTE DEL ROSARIO', '212B |EL CRISPIN', '213  |OBISPO TREJO', '214  |PIQUILLIN', '215  |PLAZA DE MERCEDES', '215A |LA QUINTA', '216  |PUNTA DEL AGUA', '217  |QUEBRACHO', '218  |RIO PRIMERO', '219  |SAGRADA FAMILIA', '220  |VILLA SANTA ROSA', '221  |EL ALCALDE', '222  |VILLA FONTANA', '223  |CANDELARIA NORTE', '224  |ENCRUCIJADA', '225  |GUTEMBERG', '225A |LA CAÑADA', '226  |LOS HOYOS', '226A |PUESTO DE CASTRO', '227  |RAYO CORTADO', '227A |RINCONADA', '227B |CERRO COLORADO', '227C |CHAÑAR VIEJO', '227D |SANTA ELENA', '228  |SEBASTIAN ELCANO', '229  |VILLA DE MARIA', '229A |EUFRASIO LOZA', '230  |CALCHIN', '230A |CALCHIN OESTE', '231  |CAPILLA DEL CARMEN', '232  |CARRILOBO', '233  |COLAZO', '234  |COSTA SACATE', '235  |LAGUNA LARGA', '236  |LAS JUNTURAS', '236A |COLONIA VIDELA', '237  |LUQUE', '237A |MANFREDI', '237B |PUEBLO LUDUEÑA', '238  |MATORRALES', '239  |ONCATIVO', '240  |PILAR', '241  |POZO DEL MOLLE', '242  |RINCON', '242A |CAÑADA DE MACHADO SUD', '243  |RIO SEGUNDO', '244  |SANTIAGO TEMPLE', '244A |LOS CHAÑARITOS', '245  |VILLA DEL ROSARIO', '248  |LABOULAYE', '249  |LA CESIRA', '251  |LEGUIZAMON', '252  |LEVALLE', '253  |MELO', '254  |RIO BAMBA', '255  |ROSALES', '256  |SAN JOAQUIN', '257  |SERRANO', '258  |VILLA ROSSI', '259  |ALTAUTINA', '260  |AMBUL', '260A |EL VOLCAN', '261  |BROCHERO', '261A |SAN LORENZO', '261B |VILLA BENEGAS', '262  |MINA CLAVERO', '263  |NONO', '263A |PAMPA DE ACHALA', '263B |LOS CERROS', '263C |ARROYO DE LOS PATOS', '263D |LAS CALLES', '263E |LAS RABONAS', '264  |PANAHOLMA', '264A |LOS ESPINILLOS', '265  |SAN PEDRO', '265A |VILLA SARMIENTO', '265B |LA CORTADERA', '265C |SAUCE ARRIBA', '266  |SAN VICENTE', '266A |SAN RAFAEL', '267  |CONLARA', '268  |DOLORES', '269  |LA PAZ', '269A |QUEBRACHO LADEADO', '269B |EL MANANTIAL', '270  |LAS ROSAS', '271  |LAS TAPIAS', '272  |LOS HORNILLOS', '273  |LUYABA', '274  |SAN JAVIER', '274A |LA POBLACION', '275  |SAN JOSE', '275A |LOS CERRILLOS', '276  |YACANTO', '277  |ALICIA', '278  |ALTOS DE CHIPION', '279  |ARROYITO', '279A |EL FUERTECITO', '280  |BALNEARIA', '281  |BEIRO', '282  |BRINKMANN', '283  |CONCEPCION', '283A |COLONIA PICHANAS', '285  |DEVOTO', '286  |DIEZ DE JULIO', '287  |DOS HERMANOS', '288  |EL ARAÑADO', '288A |VILLA SAN ESTEBAN', '289  |EL FORTIN', '290  |EL TIO', '291  |FREYRE', '291A |COLONIA ANITA', '292  |ITURRASPE', '293  |LA FRANCIA', '294  |LA PAQUITA', '294A |COLONIA VALTELINA', '295  |LA TORDILLA', '295A |TORO PUJIO', '296  |LASPIUR', '297  |LAS VARAS', '298  |LAS VARILLAS', '299  |LUXARDO', '300  |MARINA', '301  |MARULL', '302  |MAUNIER', '303  |MIRAMAR', '304  |MORTEROS', '305  |PORTEÑA', '306  |PROSPERIDAD', '307  |QUEBRACHO HERRADO', '308  |SACANTA', '309  |SAN BARTOLOME', '310  |SAN FRANCISCO SECC. SUR', '310A |SAN FRANCISCO SECC. NORTE', '311  |SAN PEDRO', '312  |SAUZE', '313  |SEEBER', '314  |TRANSITO', '315  |VIGNAUD', '316  |ALTA GRACIA', '316A |ANIZACATE', '316B |LA PAISANITA', '316C |LA RANCHERITA', '316D |LA SERRANITA', '316E |LOS CEDROS', '316F |VALLE DE ANIZACATE', '316G |VILLA EL PRADO', '316H |VILLA LA BOLSA', '316I |VILLA LOS AROMOS', '316J |VILLA PARQUE SANTA ANA', '317  |BAJO CHICO', '318  |RAFAEL GARCIA', '319  |BOUWER', '320  |BUENA VISTA', '322  |COSME', '323  |DESPEÑADEROS', '324  |FALDA DEL CARMEN', '325  |LOZADA', '326  |MALAGUEÑO', '326A |YOCSINA', '326B |BARRIO PRIMERO DE MAYO', '326C |SAN NICOLAS', '327  |MONTE RALO', '328  |POTRERO DE GARAY', '328A |LA CUMBRECITA', '328B |VILLA CIUDAD DE AMERICA', '329  |SAN CLEMENTE', '330  |SAN ISIDRO', '330A |JOSE DE LA QUINTANA', '331  |TOLEDO', '332  |POZO NUEVO', '333  |CAMINIAGA', '334  |CHUÑAHUASI', '335  |CHAÑAR', '336  |ALMAFUERTE', '337  |ASCASUBI', '337A |CNIA ALMADA', '338  |CORRALITO', '339  |DALMACIO VELEZ', '340  |HERNANDO', '341  |JAMES CRAIK', '342  |LAS PERDICES', '343  |LOS ZORROS', '344  |OLIVA', '345  |PAMPAYASTA NORTE', '346  |PAMPAYASTA SUD', '347  |PUNTA DEL AGUA', '347A |LAS ISLETILLAS', '348  |RIO TERCERO', '349  |TANCACHA', '349A |GENERAL FOTHERINGHAM', '350  |CANDELARIA', '351  |CAÑADA DE LUQUE', '351A |LA PAMPA', '352  |LAS PEÑAS', '352A |LOS MISTOLES', '353  |MACHA', '354  |SANTA CATALINA', '355  |SARMIENTO', '356  |SIMBOLAR', '357  |SINSACATE', '358  |SITON', '359  |VILLA DEL TOTORAL', '360  |CHURQUI CAÑADA', '360A |EL RODEO', '360B |LA TOMA', '361  |LAS ARRIAS', '362  |EL BAÑADO', '363  |ISLA DE SAN ANTONIO', '364  |LA DORMIDA', '365  |LAS MASITAS', '366  |LUCIO V MANSILLA', '367  |ROSARIO DEL SALADILLO', '368  |SAN JOSE DE LAS SALINAS', '369  |SAN PEDRO NORTE', '370  |SANTA CRUZ', '370A |LA CAÑADA', '371  |TULUMBA', '372  |ALTO ALEGRE', '372A |ANA ZUMARAN', '373  |BALLESTEROS', '374  |BALLESTEROS SUD', '375  |BELL VILLE', '376  |BISMARCK', '377  |BREMEN', '378  |CANALS', '379  |CARCANO', '381  |CINTRA', '382  |CHILIBROSTE', '384  |PUEBLO ITALIANO', '385  |ESCALANTE', '386  |GOULD', '387  |IDIAZABAL', '389  |LABORDE', '390  |MONTE LEÑA', '391  |MONTE MAIZ', '392  |MORRISON', '393  |NOETINGER', '394  |ORDOÑEZ', '395  |PASCANAS', '396  |POSSE', '396A |VILLA LOS PATOS', '397  |SAN ANTONIO', '397A |CORRAL DEL BAJO', '400  |SAN MARCOS SUD', '401  |SANTA MARIA', '402  |VIAMONTE']
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks. But the one I am looking for is: driver.find_element_by_id('cmbCircuitos')

Comment: I have just found out that they have the same class name. Could that be the problem?